# Is it possible to set a parameter result for a training phrase in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm currently playing around in Dialogflow trying to create a game with a certain amount of players.
I have a Set Players intent in which users can change the amount of players that will participate in the game. I've trained the intent to detect the following inputs:

1. An integer value ( "2 players will play the game")
2. @sys.Person entity ("Foo and Bar will join the game")

While these parameters wil catch most input by the users, there are still some edgecases left open, I currently cant handle sentences such as: "I want to play on my own" (1 player) or "I wish to play the game together with my friend" (2 players).

Is there a way where I can assign a value to setences like this in Dialogflow? A proper solution using a webhook, that doesn't include hardcoding strings would also be accepted.

Comment: you can select list as parameter of your name and then can check length of your @sys.Person entity

Comment: I don't think this will work when someone says "I want to play alone" or "I want to play with my friend". No name will be mentioned in the user phrase, so the length will be 0, while the user did mention 1 or 2 players.

Comment: you need to create composite entities for same with all possible words